# using Neurotechnology's Verifinger Extended SDK in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, fingerprint

We need to develop a web application that can read and enroll and verify fingerprints. We are using UareU 4500 fingerprint scanners and [Neurotechnology's](http://www.neurotechnology.com/) [Verifinger Extended SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html). We are developing in asp.net since we need to integrate this with an existing application already developed in asp.net. 
Does anyone can aoffer some pointers, tips or even better, sample code to do this in asp.net? 
Unfortunately, [Verifinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html) does not include any asp.net sample code or not even any documentation for it. We were dumb enough to buy the sdk and clients and now we are trapped with it. [Verifinger SDK](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html) documentation just says asp.net is "supported" but does not offer anything else. We have contacted  [Neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/) but their answers were evasive and obscure. 
Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you wouldn't mind doing the registration and identification of fingerprint parts of your web project in php then redirecting back to ASP.NET then I could help you outside stackoverflow as the howto will not be a straightforward answer as is required by stackoverflow. Check this link here where I developed a web fingerprint authentication module code in Php, JavaScript, HTML & MySQL for fingerprint registration and identification for that device you are using. See http://www.jomutech.co.ke/webfingerprintmod.php